# Is pushState in Backbone.js the right thing for this?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, pushstate

I am making a Node.js/Backbone.js application and wonder if I'm using pushState correctly.

My app starts at http://localhost:8888/. I want Backbone's router to pick this up and do something at index. In my app, for example, the user uploads a file and then Node.js redirects the user to http://localhost:8888/blah/. At this point I want Backbone's router to pick that URL up and do something.

At first, Backbone wasn't picking anything other than / up. I realised that Backbone of course responds to /#something etc. So I set pushState:true on Backbone's history when starting and now it seems to pick up and do the different things needed when a user is at say / or when Node.js redirects them to /blah/.

Is that right? If it works, keep it?

I basically want different JavaScript firing depending on what page the user is on. I used to do it dirty with jQuery by finding an element unique to that particular page and then fire up the needed code. But that's very dirty. This seems to work with Backbone's router, as long as I use pushState:true in the history... But is that right?

Many thanks, James

Answer (score 0):

Backbone requires you call pushState:true if you want to use it (opt-in basis).  It will fallback automatically to using the # in the URL, if the browser doesn't support pushState.

Regarding yoru description of the router, it sounds correct.  Keep in mind, without seeing code it is tough to fully know.

Lastly, you can have Backbone run a route on '/' without any problems.